# Menu item not added to actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I have looked for a solution to the problem on Stack Overflow and google, but nothing seems to help. To clarify, I am talking about the one with the id "favourite"

Here is my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.rasmase.smbcbrowser.MainActivity" >



<item android:id="@+id/favourite"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_favourite"
      android:title="@string/favourite"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/go_to_comic"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/Go_to_comic"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

And my onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Anyone else have any idea what is wrong?

EDIT:
Turns out that I am retarded. The Icon was a black star on a black actionbar. Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVWm7.png

Comment: And you are using AppCompat and your activity extends from `ActionBarActivity'?

Comment: @ianhanniballake My activity is extending from ActionBarActivity. I am also using AppCompat v7.5

Comment: app:showAsAction="never" .. you have it set to never show

Comment: @dymmeh To clarify, I am talking about the one with the id favourite.

Comment: @Rasmase - Roger that. Did you try cleaning your project and rebuilding it? Code and XML all look fine

Comment: @dymmeh Sadly, it is still not working. Really weird...

Comment: @dymmeh I kind of feel you deserve to know what went wrong. I edited the post.